# Какой роутер выбрать для домашнего сервера?

Tags: django, сервер, сеть, развертывание, роутер

есть задача запустить сайт на 200 пользователей. У меня опыта конкретно в развертывании серверов нет, поэтому могу допускать неточности в своих утверждениях, прошу исправлять.
Как я понимаю, для запуска приложения (базируется на django), нужно собрать сервер (мат.плата, процессор, 1-2 слота оперативной памяти, несколько HDD-дисков), поставить на него ОС и настроить все нужные django вещи (nginx, gunicorn, бд—postgresql), с помощью подключения ноутбука в качестве монитора. Также установить на сервер удаленный доступ (насколько опять же понимаю, по ssh, чтобы постоянно монитор не прикручивать для доступа к нему).

Однако, чтобы не растягивать объем тем, задам в этом посту вопрос только по подключению сетевого оборудования:
Посмотрел, какие тарифы доступны для подключения в моем доме, скорость на максимальном тарифе—800 мбит/с. Соответственно, сюда же нужно добавить при покупке роутера белый ip (планируется брать в качестве провайдера skynet).
Какой лучше роутер выбрать для таких задач? (очевидно, что роутер со скоростью большей 800мбит/с брать смысла не имеет из-за узкого горла)
Нужно ли предусматривать какие-либо фаэрволы или другую защиту?

Планируемая нагрузка—одновременное подключение 100 пользователей, которые имеют возможность обмениваться файлами, а также пользоваться чатом, запущенным на сайте, в том числе производить видеозвонки (используется webrtc)

Comment: Самое бюджетное оборудование в легкую справятся с вашими 100 подключениями одновременно) даже вообще без роутера и тд) просо если нокиа 3310 впихнете....

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а есть ли какая-нибудь таблица, в которой скорости роутера соответствует количество одновременный подключений?

Comment: И правильно ли я понимаю, что если пропускная способность 800мбит/с, а подключится одновременно 100 человек и начнет загружать файлы, то в среднем пропускная способность на каждого будет 1МБ/с?